# How to store an NSArray in an NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to teach myself but am struggling with how to store something like an NSArray inside an NSDictionary.

Let's say hypothetically you had a NSDictionary for recipes:

Let's say the NSDictionary had keys like:

Spaghetti,
Fettucine Alfredo,
Grilled Chicken Salad

And the NSDictionary had an NSArray which was simply a list of ingredients.

I suppose the equivalent PHP code would be something like:

```
$['Spaghetti'] = array('Spaghetti Pasta', 'Spaghetti Sauce', 'Meatballs');
$['Fettucine Alfredo'] = array('Fettucine Pasta', 'Alfredo Sauce');
$['Grilled Chicken Salad'] = array('Lettuce', 'Grilled Chicken', 'Croutons');
```

I'm struggling with how I can add an NSArray to the NSDictionary. Then what if I wanted to remove an element or add an element to the array? How is it retrieved and deleted or added to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Spaghetti Pasta", @"Tomato Sauce", nil], @"Spaghetti",
  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Fettuccine Pasta", @"Alfredo Sauce", nil], @"Fettuccine Alfredo",
  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Lettuce", @"Grilled Chicken", @"Croutons", nil], @"Grilled Chicken Salad",
  nil];
```

You can add any object type to a dictionary as a value. For more on dictionaries, see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).